# Firebase audience not being populated after several days

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm attempting to build a Firebase audience for my Android app based on users who live in the United States.  From what I've gathered, users' countries are a property that's gathered out of the box simply by integrating with the Firebase SDK.  I built an audience in the analytics dashboard (criteria is user property -> country -> exactly matches 'US'), but I still haven't seen any users populated in the audience.  It's been over 3 days since I created the audience, as I've read from several other questions that the audience is not populated retroactively.

I also tried creating a separate audience for users that are on the latest version of my app, and that audience hasn't gathered any users either since it was created.

Here's a screenshot of my audience configurations
[image]

[image]

Is there anything I could be missing here, or is this a potential bug in Firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To become audience member a user needs to trigger an event and match all the conditions in the audience. Using country as the only condition will not automatically make all users that are in US members as there is nothing to trigger the audience evaluation.

Also audiences are sticky so your audience is users who are in US or have been in US at any time in the past since you defined the audience.

You have two options to make this work:

1. You don't need to define audience for location. Every event has the current location already and you can use location to target push notifications or change remote config values. Its redundant to define location as audience.
2. Add common event as audience trigger to your audience. You can use  something like [session_start](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event). This will make audience evaluated every time "session_start" event is triggered. Once the user location matches and the user starts a session he/she will become a member. The membership is sticky so your audience is users who have started session while in the US not users who are in the US now. If you want users in the US now use option 1.

Comment: Thanks, I believe my issue was that I do not have events that are being triggered often enough.  I am now starting to see users populated in the audiences I created.